# background-position question

Tags: background, background-position

On  [**this page I"ve been working on forever**](http://www.sellmycalls.com/cgi-bin/chain), I have this column headed "Bid x Ask": http://www.sellmycalls.com/so-bg-pos.png

in each of whose cell backgrounds there is supposed to be a bar chart that conveys the ratio of the numbers in the cell to each other.

So in each cell I have a background-color: gray; and a background-image:all-white;. I can't properly position the (plenty big enough) image on the gray background. In fact, in its current incarnation, the image doesn't show up at all.

How can I properly set the background-position of the image? The top <td> in the column is styled this way:

```
   <td class="main_td bxa bxa_val"
   style="background-color: #ecf1ef;
          background-image:url('http://www.sellmycalls.com/pics/cell/bxa-white.png');
          background-repeat:repeat-x repeat-y;
          background-origin: 0px 0px;
          background-attachment:fixed;
          background-position:53px 0px;
     -moz-background-position:53px 0px;
  -webkit-background-position:53px 0px;
   -khtml-background-position:53px 0px;
  -o-user-background-position:53px 0px;">
    <div>&nbsp;543 x 470</div></td>
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your image is `49x1px` which I think is showing, however, with Firebug your `TD` shows a style of `background-repeat:repeat-x;` X not Y as you show in your example code snippet above.

UPDATE:

Try

```
style="background-color:#ecf1ef;
       background-image:url('http://www.sellmycalls.com/pics/cell/bxa-white.png');
       background-position:50px 0px;
       background-repeat:repeat-y;"
```

- you cannot adjust the dimensions of the image so (1) always make the image at least as wide as the TD itself (i.e. wider than 49px) and always use the background-image as the right hand side bar and the background-color for the left side bar. I hope this is all clear

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake. I gave the image repeat-y and now it seems to show with background-position:0px 0px where I want it to be background-position:50px 0px approx. So where is it getting that background-image x-offset from? Thanks.

Comment: Pete - I'm still playing with this in Firebug for you - can you pls upload a 1px x 1px image - it MAY be that your img width of 49px is not allowing you to offset x px. Also from what I'm reading `background-origin` does NOT accept numeric values - see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-origin.asp

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to evaporate while you were working on my stuff -- actually I know guys who *do* that :-) I put a 1px x 1px img up at http://www.sellmycalls.com/mud1x1.png  Mud is its name and mud is its color: best color I can get out my new paint program just now.

Comment: Pete - try `style="background-color:#ecf1ef;background-image:url('http://www.sellmycalls.com/pics/cell/bxa-white.png');background-position:50px 0px;background-repeat:repeat-y;"` - you cannot adjust the dimensions of the image so (1) always make the image at least as wide as the TD itself (i.e. wider than 49px) and always use the background-image as the right hand side bar and the background-color for the left side bar. I hope this is all clear.

Comment: Perfect! Take a look now. My cgi calcs are off, but that's just exactly the appearance I was after. Thanks so much! Please make your comments an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Honestly, thanks so, so much. I couldn'a done it widout cha, I was so discouraged and pissed off.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your image's path is incorrect. However the `div` child of each cell has a background-color rule, so this color cover any background of `<td>`

Comment: I don't see the background-color rule you mention. Could you please point me to a line number in the view source? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake ^^' But the path of your image I see still doesn't seem to be correct.

Comment: The full path is **http://www.sellmycalls.com/pics/cell/bxa-white.png**. Is it *still* wrong the way you see it?

Comment: yep, chrome is seeing me sellmycalls.com/cgi-bin/pics/cell/bxa-white.png

Comment: sorry to be so long away. How about *now?* I put the entire path into the background-image url.